# Add bank details tab and input field in woocommerce my account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add bank details of user from tab bank details i need help i am not able to submit the form and want this data to save and display in show_user_profile[image: This is where i add]

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'bbloomer_remove_address_my_account', 999 );
 
function bbloomer_remove_address_my_account( $items ) {
unset($items['downloads']);
return $items;
}
function iconic_account_menu_items( $items ) {
unset($items['customer-logout']);
    $items['information'] = __( 'Bank Details', 'iconic' );
    $items['customer-logout'] = __( 'Logout');

    return $items;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'iconic_account_menu_items', 10, 1 );
function iconic_add_my_account_endpoint() {
 
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'information', EP_PAGES );
 
}
 

add_action( 'init', 'iconic_add_my_account_endpoint' );
function iconic_get_account_fields() {
   echo "Please enter bank details";
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); ?>

<form  action="" method="post">
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
  <label for="acc_number"><?php esc_html_e( 'Account Number', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="acc_number" id="acc_number" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->acc_number); ?>" />
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
  <label for="acc_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Account Name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="acc_name" id="acc_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->acc_name); ?>" />
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
  <label for="acc_ifsc"><?php esc_html_e( 'Bank IFSC', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="acc_ifsc" id="acc_ifsc" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->acc_ifsc); ?>" />
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
  <label for="acc_type"><?php esc_html_e( 'Type of Account', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="acc_type" id="acc_type" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->acc_type); ?>" />

<p>
  
  <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="save_bankdetails" value="save_bankdetails">Submit Details</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="save_bankdetails" value="save_bankdetails" />
 </p>

</form>



 <?php }

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_information_endpoint', 'iconic_get_account_fields' );
function iconic_is_endpoint( $endpoint = false ) {
 
    global $wp_query;
 
    if( !$wp_query )
        return false;
 
    return isset( $wp_query->query[ $endpoint ] );
 
}
```

As if any thing would be wrong please let me know i am new to this so.

Your help will be appreciated